# what is \r in python 3.5.2? (pycharm & Mac)

Tags: python-3.x

I am running codes in python 3.5.2 in mac. (pycharm)

When I run print("abcz\rdef"), I was expecting to get defz, but I got def...
What is happening right now?

Comment: @YOU `\r` is the newline for Mac, not Windows. Windows uses `\r\n`

Comment: that knowledge is out of date

Comment: @YOU referencing Windows was always wrong. It never used `\r`

Comment: tell me which OS X use \r

Comment: @jin, try sys.stdout.write("abcz\rdef"), I guess pycharm trying to be interactive your input.

Answer (score 2):

**ASCII Char** `\r` **aka.** `0x0D` **aka.** `13` **aka.** `^M`:**
First, it's not a Python property, but a common ASCII code. This means that pretty much all programing languages will behave the same to the **character** `\r`.
Note the singular: `\r` is **ONE** char.

---

**Carriage Return**

This said, it correspond to [Carriage Return (CR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), which, basically goes back to the begining of the line.

In your case you say "plz print **abcz** then go back to the begining and print **def**". "Going back to the begining" means that you will overwrite on the current line. So `def` overwrite `abc`, the `z` is left as is, giving you `defz` in the end.

**ex**:

```
print("a\rb") # => b
print("abcdef\rLOL") #=> LOLdef
#etc...
```

---

**Newline: LF vs CR+LF:**

The fact is that newlines are not handled the exact same way depending on your OS. Most of OS will use a single `\n` for newlines, while Windows uses `\r\n` which can cause strange troubles (see examples below).

Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

> ```
> LF:    Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, Multics, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS, and others[1]
> CR+LF: Microsoft Windows, DOS (MS-DOS, PC DOS, etc.), DEC TOPS-10, RT-11, CP/M, MP/M, Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS, Amstrad CPC, and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes
> CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Oberon, the classic Mac OS up to version 9, MIT Lisp Machine and OS-9
> RS:    QNX pre-POSIX implementation
> 0x9B:  Atari 8-bit machines using ATASCII variant of ASCII (155 in decimal)
> LF+CR: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.
> ```

---

**Common Problem:**
I guess the most common problem is reading line by line Windows text file on Linux. As a Linux dev you will expect line to end with `\n` and, let say you want to concat sentences, you will remove only the `\n` leaving a dangerous `\r` inside.

Example: we want to concatenate each sentence from two files.

```
# Open our two files
fn1="file1.txt"
fn2="file2.txt"

f1=open(fn1, 'r')
f2=open(fn2, 'r')

while True:
   # Read 1 line in each
   l1 = f1.readline()
   l2 = f2.readline()

   # Check lines are not empty, or break
   if not l1 or not l2:
      break

   # Remove new lines
   l1 = l1.replace('\n', '')
   l2 = l2.replace('\n', '')

   # Print the result
   print("%s %s" % (l1, l2))
```

In the above example, if `l1` comes from Windows, you will only see `l2` printed. (In fact its overwritten, so if `l1` is longer that `l2` you will see `l2`+ the end of `l1`)

---

**Exemple:**
A pretty cool example is to make a counter increase a number without printing new line, try this:

```
for i in range(100000):
   print("\r%d" % i, end="")
```

`pltrdy`

Comment: `\r` is the newline for *Mac*, not Windows

Comment: I just said Windows uses CRLF, not CR, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question. As I tried your example:
   (print("a\rb") # => b
   print("abcdef\rLOL") #=> LOLdef

I still got b and LOL for the answers....
I don't know why it keeps happening... 
I am using pycharm by the way... Let me know how I fix it...